# get checked checkBoxes texts in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I have 4 checkBox in my windows form application and I need to get the text of checked checkBox by returning it from a string function but it gives me an exception. The codes of the function are:

```
string getPerm()
{
   string perm = "";
   foreach(CheckBox chkb in this.Controls)
   {
       if(chkb.Checked==true)
       {
           perm += chkb.Text + ",";
       }
   }
   return perm;
}
```

And I used this function in Show method of messageBox to show the result on click event of a button , one more problem is that I need to delete the last comma from the result... regards

Comment: _but it gives me an exception_  I have an idea of what exception, nevertheless you shouldn't be so vague. Explain what exception you get.

Comment: @Steve I bet that exception pops up due to CheckBox cast. Not all controls might be CheckBoxes.

Comment: if( chkb is ChaeckBox && chkb.Checked==true)

Answer (score 3):

You can use LINQ to join texts:

```
return string.Join(",", this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>.Where(x => x.Checked).Select(x => x.Text));
```

Your code is not working due to implicit `CheckBox` cast in the `foreach` loop. Given that not all of your controls are `CheckBox`es (and this is most likely true), the `InvalidCastException` will pop up. `OfType<T>` method will make sure that only `CheckBox`es will be used in the query.

Additional readings:

[Control.Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Enumerable.OfType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx)